# Difference of here string' and a empty file (BASH)

Tags: string, bash, input

During a playing with **md5sum** I've found something that catch my curiosity. Consider the following example where ">>>" denotes output.

```
# ◈ CASE A ◈
mdf5sum <&1
#  And press <CRTL+D>, expecting fulfill with a empty data
>>> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e


# ◇ CASE B ◇
mdf5sum <<< ''
>>> 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940

### TL;DR; trying to undestand Case B
###+       is the reason for this question.
###        Skip other examples if they'll bore you.

# ◇ CASE C ◇
mdf5sum <&1 
# pressing <ENTER> and <CTRL+D>
>>> 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940


# ◈ CASE D ◈
mdf5sum << EOF
EOF
>>>d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e


# ◇ CASE F ◇
mdf5sum << EOF


EOF
>>>68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940


# ◈ CASE G ◈
touch /tmp/file.empty
md5sum /tmp/file.empty
>>>d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

I wrote "<&1" to emphasize the origin of the input (standard input).

My doubt is CASE A and B should be equal in my (naive) understanding, once in both no char was read. Why not?

So... how can I explain case B correctly?

Comment: Read the manual. It says *The result is supplied as a single string, **with a newline appended**,*; so a character was actually read in case B.

Comment: I was sure that is a "stupid" issue like this one.